# Show the full contents of a list in python with print

Tags: python, arrays, debugging

I am trying to debug the output of some list manipulations, so I have `print ar` in various places. However the output is always of the form:

```
[[255,255,255],
[255,255,255],
[255,255,255],
...,
[255,255,255],
[255,255,255],
[255,255,255]]
```

which is useless for what I am trying to do since most of the list is missing in the `...,` (in fact all of the list that is not filler data is in there). How can I get it to show the ENTIRE list to me so I can figure out if my manipulations are doing what they are supposed to be doing?

Comment: This is not normal Python list behaviour - is this a Numpy array?

Comment: Are you sure there are no brackets outside the `...`?

Comment: Does this occur for all long lists? For example, if you do `print range(10000)`, does the `...` appear in the place of the correct contents?

Comment: Turns out this is in fact a numpy list.

Answer (score 2):

`...` is Python's way of telling you that you have nested a list within itself (you're recursively referencing the list) and it can't possibly print that as it would go on forever.

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [...]]
```

Comment: I see that your answer is correct but I don't understand why it wouldn't be able to print it. Shouldn't it print something like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]`

Comment: You're missing a third element in the nested list you printed and one within it and so on. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this code, should solve your issue.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)


with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(df)
```

Source: [Here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+show+the+full+list+in+pandas)